Problema de interrupción dentro del while con un boton
Estoy programando un Atmega1284P en la plataforma de Arduino de platform.io.
Esta es una función que controla el echado del líquido controlado con una báscula de peso llamando a la función pesoActual().
En cuando paso a la condición del while para llegar al pesoPorechar que es la condición de la salida del while.
Quiero añadir una función de pausa para esta función pulsando un botón de pausa : botonPausa.pulsado() que viene de una librería de botón que funciona
correctamente.
El problema que tengo que cuando pulso en el botón de pausa no se detiene la función y no pasa a la función correspondiente de pausar el echado para pulsar otra vez en el mismo botón y reanudar el proceso pausado.
La función de reanudar al pulsar el botón en el while que está en el agotado funciona correctamente en cuando pulso el mismo botón y regresa al proceso.
void Mezclas::echarLiquido(int16_t pesoPorechar)
{
  // Encender la bomba correspondiente
  encenderBombaCorrespondiente();

  unsigned long tiempoInicioMezcla = millis(); 
  unsigned long tiempoUltimaVariacion = millis();
  pesoLiquido = PesoActual();
  pesoRelative = 0;

  EEPROM.get(PESO_RELATIVO_ADDRESS, pesoRelative);
  // Mostrar el mensaje adecuado en el LCD
  mostrarLiquido();
  delay(50);

  while (pesoRelative < pesoPorechar)
  {
    if(botonPausa.pulsado())
    {
      delay(20);
      pausarReanudarMezcla();
    }

    // Reanudar la función
    if (enPausa)
    {
      esperarParaReanudar();
    }

    mostrarLiquido();  
    
    if (millis() - tiempoInicioMezcla > tiempoErrorBomba)
    {
      lcd.clear();
      delay(20);
      lcd.setCursor(1,0);
      lcd.print("ERROR BOMBA");
      delay(8000);
      apagarBombas();
      return;
    }
    int16_t nuevoPesoActual = PesoActual();

    
    if (nuevoPesoActual != pesoLiquido)
    {
      tiempoUltimaVariacion = millis(); // Reiniciar el temporizador si hay cambio en el peso
    }
    //  Caso del agotado porque no se cambia el peso; el proceso se pausa hasta pulsar en el boton pausa
    if (millis() - tiempoUltimaVariacion > 10000) // Si no hay cambio en el peso por 5 segundos
    {
      mostrarAgotado();
      apagarBombas();

      // Esperar hasta que el usuario presione el botón de inicio para continuar
      while (!botonPausa.pulsado())
      {
        delay(300);
      }

      // Reiniciar la bomba correspondiente
      encenderBombaCorrespondiente();

      // Reiniciar el tiempo de última variación
      tiempoUltimaVariacion = millis();
    }

    // Finalizar el proceso y salir del while 
    nuevoPesoActual = PesoActual();
    pesoRelative += nuevoPesoActual - pesoLiquido;
    pesoLiquido = nuevoPesoActual;
    EEPROM.put(PESO_RELATIVO_ADDRESS, pesoRelative);
    updateProgressBar(pesoRelative, pesoPorechar, 1); 
    delay(500);
  }
  
  // Finalizar el proceso y salir de la función
  pesoLiquido = PesoActual();
  EEPROM.put(PESO_ACEITE_ACTUAL_ADRESS, pesoLiquido);
  EEPROM.put(PESO_RELATIVO_ADDRESS, 0);
  
  // Apagar la bomba correspondiente
  apagarBombas();
  delay(1000);
}

// Función de pausa 
void Mezclas::pausarReanudarMezcla()
{
  enPausa = !enPausa;
  if (enPausa)
  {
    // Pantalla de pausa
    Pantallamezcla(8);
  }
  else
  {
    // Pantalla de reanudar
    Pantallamezcla(9);
    delay(3000);
  }
}

// Función de reanudar
void Mezclas::esperarParaReanudar()
{
  while (enPausa)
  {
    // Esperar hasta que se reanude la mezcla
    if (botonPausa.pulsado())
    {
      pausarReanudarMezcla();
    }
  }
}


Es imprescindible que nos diga que librería estás ocupando para leer el botón. Por favor, el nombre y la URL de donde la sacastes.

Por lo general, este tipo de librería requiere que llames periódicamente a una función de actualización, que se encarga de ver si está pulsado o no.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iWfK3j_FLDurNA0eZgfoIRFEAaIFyM7h-cQfvtY6jF8/edit?usp=sharing

Aqui esta el enlace para el codigo general :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zhX5UVw2KoGcU70Bsr-A45iGgaxKI196IrfAks3A_VM/edit?usp=sharing

Deberías llamar a Boton::update() en cada pasada por loop. Si demoras mucho tiempo entre cada llamada a update(), es posible que no detectes las pulsaciones. Es necesario que elimines los delay() sobre 100ms e implementes una máquina de estado para transaccionar entre los estados. Si presionas el botón durante un delay(), va a pasar inadvertido.

en la loop del main solo tengo las condiciones de botones porque tengo varios y que gestionan otras funciones de mi menu principal:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T5GWkF0AiUZxEUfT92niK_YhLHC9KaXa3Ht09VL7FZ0/edit?usp=sharing
En el caso de eliminar los delays puedo sistituirlos con millis() o no hace falta dejarlos de forma definitiva ?
Pero si estoy en un bucle while la funcion loop() no va ejecutarse, por eso aunque llamo continuamente al update() no me va a servir supongo

El concepto central es que no puedes hacer esperas ni ciclos dentro de loop (a menos que sean bien cortos). Si tienes (por ejemplo) que iterar 10 elementos, donde cada uno se demora 300 ms, deberías procesar uno por cada pasada de loop, anotando en cual índice vas y cuando te toca procesar el siguiente. Hice una app parecida a la tuya y la base es un task scheduler que en cada pasada de loop revisa a que tareas les llego la hora y entonces las ejecuta.

Bueno nunca he trabajado con el task scheduler pero solo con maquina de estados, pero si te fijas que en el loop no hay delays ni nada de eso.
Principalmente mi aplicacion es una maquina de estados de menus que se controla con dos botones Up Y Down y un Set para entrar en el menu y un Sel para comenzar una funcion o una tarea.
en esta función en el que tengo el problema es para controlar el echado de liquido en un dicho proceso, quiero cambiar el while () que controla el peso y sustituir un if o una maquina de estados para evitar el loop
Voy a intentar cambiar el método y haber que pasa
